# Disable a Shiny-input which is conditional on another Shiny-input

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I am trying to disable a `Shiny-input`, whose value is conditional on another `Shiny-input`. Previously I looked in the `disable()` function from `shinyjs`, however it appears that, in my case, it fails to disable such Shiny-input. Below is my example :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    sliderInput(inputId = "First", label = "First",
                      min = 10, max = 100, value = 40, step = 1),

    uiOutput("Second_UI")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$Second_UI = renderUI({
              sliderInput(inputId = "Second", label = "Second", 
                min = 0, max = input$First, value = 5)       
            })

    disable("Second_UI")

  }
))
```

What I basically, want is - my 2nd `sliderInput` i.e. `Second` will still take value from `First` responsively, however User should not be able to control it.

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

The reason this will not work is that you render the element a lot of times, but disable it only once in your script - before the element is actually rendered.

However, we can solve this quite simply actually; `Shinyjs` provides a `disabled` function that allows you to initialize an input as disabled. So a working exampleis given below.

Hope this helps!

---

[image]

---

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    sliderInput(inputId = "First", label = "First",
                min = 10, max = 100, value = 40, step = 1),
    uiOutput("Second_UI")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$Second_UI = renderUI({
      shinyjs::disabled(sliderInput(inputId = "Second", label = "Second", 
                  min = 0, max = input$First, value = 5))
    })
  }
))
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer by @Florian is correct (and thanks for using my shinyjs package!).

However, I'd like to offer an alternative implementation to your original code that may be a bit cleaner and easier.

Instead of creating the slider as a renderUI, since the only thing that changes is the maximum value, you can use the `updateSliderInput()` function to just change the maximum value every time. This way the element itself is only created once, it's a bit faster and easier to work with.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
runApp(shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        useShinyjs(),
        sliderInput(inputId = "First", label = "First",
                    min = 10, max = 100, value = 40, step = 1),
        sliderInput(inputId = "Second", label = "Second", 
                    min = 0, max = 40, value = 5)
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session) {
        observe({
            updateSliderInput(session, "Second", max = input$First)
        })

        disable("Second")

    }
))
```